# Parse replaces Core Data? iOS

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, parse-platform, nsuserdefaults

I am developing an app where I am going to use NSUserDefaults to store some profile variables (name, picture, etc), I think.

I think I need to store some long huge lists of values for each user and I read about Parse and Core Data. What is the best? Can Parse replace Core Data?

What is useful on this case? Both?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Parse will store your data on their infrastructure on the cloud. You can enable Parse object caching to keep that data for offline use as well. For most apps I build, I avoid using CoreData (although Parse may be internally using some for of local store, could be CoreData) and use Parse explicitly with caching.